# When is a positive semi-definite matrix A positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does it has something to do with the determinant of A? I saw two seperate websites - one which claims that when the determinant of A is zero, and the other claims that when the determinant of A is not zero, then the positive semi-definite matrix is positive definite.

Can someone explain to me which is the correct answer, and the reason behind it?
Thank you.

Comment: take a look: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_criterion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the determinant of a positive semi-definite matrix is not zero (i.e., the matrix is non-singular), then it is positive definite. Because, determinant=Product of eigenvalues and a positive definite matrix have all positive (strictly greater than zero) eigenvalues.

Comment: Yeah.  PSD means the eigenvalues are all >= 0.  PD means the eigenvalues are all > 0.  The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues.  Best way to think of the difference between PD and SPD IMO.