# Is Positive Semi-Definiteness of a Matrix a loose measure of Independence?

Tags: matrices, independence, covariance, correlation, positive-semidefinite

I am trying to understand D-optimality criteria which tends to minimize the covariance matrix between two random variables. Now keeping that aside and in general, having PSD of a covariance matrix imply that the random variables are linearly independent?

Also for the reference I found this answer

> [determinant=Product of eigenvalues and a positive definite matrix have all positive (strictly greater than zero) eigenvalues.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72119/when-is-a-positive-semi-definite-matrix-a-positive-definite)

So does having an eigen value greater then 0 imply that there is a correlation and if so does it make another loose measure of independence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> having PSD of a covariance matrix imply that the random variables are linearly independent

No, all covariance matrices are PSD.

> So does having an eigen value greater then 0 imply that there is a correlation and if so does it make another loose measure of independence?

If you have **all** eigenvalues greater than zero, then the covariance matrix will be PD. And you will be able to use a [whitening transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation) to transform your original random vector $X$ into a $Y$ that is uncorrelated. Just having uncorrelatedness is not enough for you to claim they are independent, in general.

But, if you are dealing with a random vector $X$ with a **multivariate normal distribution**, you can conclude that after the transformation the components of $Y$ are not only uncorrelated, but also independent.

Comment: I want to ask why is `having uncorrelatedness is not enough for you to claim they are independent, in general.`? What more is required

Comment: +1 for adding reference to whitening transformation

Comment: There are a few questions in MathSE that deal with that, and why it works for jointly Gaussian distributions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144318/uncorrelated-and-independent-random-variables https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609732/jointly-gaussian-uncorrelated-random-variables-are-independent https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215345/uncorrelated-but-not-independent-random-variables